# Is there anyway to group data by non synchronized in 1 of 2 columns in oracle sql?

Tags: php, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using Group by statement to summary data by 2 columns, the problem is 1 or 2 columns sometimes have null value, so it cause some unexpected result.

Example:

```
+--------+----------+----------+-------------+---------+
| EMP_ID | EMP_NAME | EMP_CODE + EMP_ID_CARD | EMP_FEE |
|--------+----------+----------+-------------|---------|
|0001    + John     + 1234     + 000001      | 250     |
|--------+----------+----------+-------------|---------|
|0002    + Kate     + 1122     + 000002      | 150     |
|--------+----------+----------+-------------|---------|
|0002    + Kate     + 1122     + 000002      | 300     |
|--------+----------+----------+-------------|---------|
|0001    + John     + 1234     + NULL        | 100     |
+--------+----------+----------+-------------+---------+
```

With SQL query:

```
SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, EMP_CODE, EMP_ID_CARD, SUM(EMP_FEE) FEE
FROM table_name
GROUP BY EMP_NAME, EMP_CODE, EMP_ID_CARD
```

Expect result is:

```
+--------+----------+----------+-------------+---------+
| EMP_ID | EMP_NAME | EMP_CODE + EMP_ID_CARD | EMP_FEE |
|--------+----------+----------+-------------|---------|
|0001    + John     + 1234     + 000001      | 350     |
|--------+----------+----------+-------------|---------|
|0002    + Kate     + 1122     + 000002      | 450     |
+--------+----------+----------+-------------|---------+
```

But i get the result is:

```
+--------+----------+----------+-------------+---------+
| EMP_ID | EMP_NAME | EMP_CODE + EMP_ID_CARD | EMP_FEE |
|--------+----------+----------+-------------|---------|
|0001    + John     + 1234     + 000001      | 250     |
|--------+----------+----------+-------------|---------|
|0002    + Kate     + 1122     + 000002      | 450     |
|--------+----------+----------+-------------|---------|
|0001    + John     + 1234     + NULL        | 100     |
+--------+----------+----------+-------------|---------+
```

I know that the group by will ignore the same emp_name and emp_code but with null emp_id_card it will know as a new one.

Answer (score 1):

add `count()` this will separate `NULL`

```
SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, EMP_CODE, EMP_ID_CARD, SUM(EMP_FEE) FEE, count(*) AS counts
FROM table_name
GROUP BY EMP_NAME, EMP_CODE, EMP_ID_CARD
```

expected output will be:

```
+--------+----------+----------+-------------+---------+--------+
| EMP_ID | EMP_NAME | EMP_CODE + EMP_ID_CARD | EMP_FEE | counts |
|--------+----------+----------+-------------|---------|--------|
|0001    + John     + 1234     + 000001      | 250     | 1      |
|--------+----------+----------+-------------|---------|--------|
|0002    + Kate     + 1122     + 000002      | 450     | 2      |
|--------+----------+----------+-------------|---------|--------|
|0001    + John     + 1234     + NULL        | 100     | 1      |
+--------+----------+----------+-------------|---------+--------+
```